# How to handle/cancel back navigation in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

I tried to use the back navigation by overriding `OnBackButtonPressed`, but somehow it wasn't get called at all. I am using the `ContentPage` and the latest 1.4.2 release.

Comment: I believe that event is specifically for the Android hardware back button, not for general "back" navigation events.

Comment: I know. I tried on Android and the hardware back button, not getting called

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Alright, after many hours I figured this one out. There are three parts to it.

#1 Handling the hardware back button on android. This one is easy, override OnBackButtonPressed. Remember, this is for a hardware back button and android only. It will not handle the navigation bar back button. As you can see, I was trying to back through a browser before backing out of the page, but you can put whatever logic you need in.

```
  protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if (_browser.CanGoBack)
        {
            _browser.GoBack();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //await Navigation.PopAsync(true);
            base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

#2 iOS navigation back button. This one was really tricky, if you look around the web you'll find a couple examples of replacing the back button with a new custom button, but it's almost impossible to get it to look like your other pages. In this case I made a transparent button that sits on top of the normal button.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyAdvantagePage), typeof

(MyAdvantagePageRenderer))]
namespace Advantage.MyAdvantage.MobileApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class MyAdvantagePageRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            if (((MyAdvantagePage)Element).EnableBackButtonOverride)
            {
                SetCustomBackButton();
            }
        }
        private void SetCustomBackButton()
        {
            UIButton btn = new UIButton();
            btn.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 50, 40);
            btn.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

            btn.TouchDown += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Whatever your custom back button click handling
                if (((MyAdvantagePage)Element)?.
                CustomBackButtonAction != null)
                {
                    ((MyAdvantagePage)Element)?.
                       CustomBackButtonAction.Invoke();
                }
            };
            NavigationController.NavigationBar.AddSubview(btn);
        }
    }
}
```

Android, is tricky. In older versions and future versions of Forms once fixed, you can simply override the OnOptionsItemselected like this

```
       public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        // check if the current item id 
        // is equals to the back button id
        if (item.ItemId == 16908332)
        {
            // retrieve the current xamarin forms page instance
            var currentpage = (MyAdvantagePage)
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.
            Current.MainPage.Navigation.
            NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();

            // check if the page has subscribed to 
            // the custom back button event
            if (currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction != null)
            {
                // invoke the Custom back button action
                currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction.Invoke();
                // and disable the default back button action
                return false;
            }

            // if its not subscribed then go ahead 
            // with the default back button action
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        else
        {
            // since its not the back button 
            //click, pass the event to the base
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

However, if you are using FormsAppCompatActivity, then you need to add onto your OnCreate in MainActivity this to set your toolbar:

```
Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

But wait! If you have too old a version of .Forms or too new version, a bug will come up where toolbar is null. If this happens, the hacked together way I got it to work to make a deadline is like this. In `OnCreate` in `MainActivity`:

```
        MobileApp.Pages.Articles.ArticleDetail.androdAction = () =>
        {
            Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        };
```

ArticleDetail is a Page, and androidAction is an `Action` that I run on OnAppearing if the Platform is Android on my page. By this point in your app, toolbar will no longer be null.

Couple more steps, the iOS render we made above uses properties that you need to add to whatever page you are making the renderer for. I was making it for my `MyAdvantagePage` class that I made, which implements ContentPage . So in my `MyAdvantagePage` class I added

```
public Action CustomBackButtonAction { get; set; }

        public static readonly BindableProperty EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty =
               BindableProperty.Create(
               nameof(EnableBackButtonOverride),
               typeof(bool),
               typeof(MyAdvantagePage),
               false);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets Custom Back button overriding state
        /// </summary>
        public bool EnableBackButtonOverride
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)GetValue(EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(EnableBackButtonOverrideProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

Now that that is all done, on any of my `MyAdvantagePage` I can add this

```
:


 this.EnableBackButtonOverride = true;
            this.CustomBackButtonAction = async () =>
            {
                if (_browser.CanGoBack)
                {
                    _browser.GoBack();
                }
                else
                {
                    await Navigation.PopAsync(true);
                }
            };
```

That should be everything to get it to work on Android hardware back, and navigation back for both android and iOS.

Comment: So... turns out if you have a TabbedPage and use my awful hack to get around the Xamarin.Forms bug, that it only catches the back button override on the back button on the first page, apparently the back buttons on other pages are different...? Does anyone have a fix for all tabs?

Comment: What is this line? MobileApp.Pages.Articles.ArticleDetail.androdAction. I can't figure out how to resolve what all that is. What using do I need to include?

Comment: @Andrew I tried to explain it just below it. ArticleDetail  is a `Page` and `androdAction` is an Action I added to my Page class. I override OnAppearing  on my page and run that action during that event.

Answer (score 18):

You are right, in your page class override `OnBackButtonPressed` and return `true` if you want to prevent navigation. It works fine for me and I have the same version.

```cs
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    if (Condition)
        return true;
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

Comment: It seems that there is a bug in Xamarin Forms which says that if I use a TabbedPage as root page, then the OnBackButtonPressed won't get called. I was told by a guy seemingly comes from Xamarin

Comment: How do I obtain the page that is being navigated to?

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.OnBackButtonPressed()/) say "This event is not raised on iOS."

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what exactly you are looking for (I would not recommend using this if you simply want to cancel back button navigation), `OnDisappearing` may be another option:

```cs
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
       //back button logic here
}
```

Comment: When I tried by overriding OnDisappear there are two problems:
1. The page has already visually disappeared so the "Are you sure?" dialog appears over the previous page.
2. Cannot cancel the back action.

Comment: [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21631/is-there-nay-way-of-cancelling-the-back-button-event-from-the-navigationpage) are platform specific solutions

Comment: On OnDisappearing function is called also when you lock your phones screen or when you switch to another app. not only when you navigate to previous page

Answer (score 2):

OnBackButtonPressed() this will be called when a hardware back button is pressed as in android. **This will not work on the software back button press as in ios.**

Answer (score 2):

Additional to Kyle Answer
Set

Inside YOURPAGE

```
public static Action SetToolbar;
```

YOURPAGE OnAppearing

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
{
    SetToolbar.Invoke();
}
```

MainActivity

```
YOURPAGE.SetToolbar = () =>
{
    Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = 
        this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/index.html) libray and for handle the back button/action I extend `INavigatedAware` interface of Prism on my page and I implement this methods:

```
    public void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.GetNavigationMode() == NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            //Your code
        }
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
    }
```

Method OnNavigatedFrom is raised when user press back button from Navigation Bar (Android & iOS) and when user press Hardware back button (only for Android).

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            base.OnBackButtonPressed();
                return true;
        }
```

`base.OnBackButtonPressed()` returns false on click of hardware back button. 
In order to prevent operation of back button or prevent navigation to previous page. the overriding function should be returned as true. On return true, it stays on the current xamarin form page and state of page is also maintained.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still fighting with this issue - basically you cannot intercept back navigation cross-platform. Having said that there are two approaches that effectively solve the problem:

1. Hide the NavigationPage back button with `NavigationPage.ShowHasBackButton(this, false)` and push a modal page that has a custom Back/Cancel/Close button
2. Intercept the back navigation natively for each platform. This is a good article that does it for iOS and Android: https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/

For UWP you are on your own :)

Edit:

Well, not anymore since I did it :) It actually turned out to be pretty easy – there is just one back button and it’s supported by Forms so you just have to override ContentPage’s OnBackButtonPressed:

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform.Equals(Device.UWP))
        {
            OnClosePageRequested();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            return false;
        }
    }

    async void OnClosePageRequested()
    {
        var tdvm = (TaskDetailsViewModel)BindingContext;
        if (tdvm.CanSaveTask())
        {
            var result = await DisplayAlert("Wait", "You have unsaved changes! Are you sure you want to go back?", "Discard changes", "Cancel");

            if (result)
            {
                tdvm.DiscardChanges();
                await Navigation.PopAsync(true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await Navigation.PopAsync(true);
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to implement your own navigation page that inherits from `NavigationPage`. It has the appropriate events `Pushed`, `Popped` and `PoppedToRoot`.

A sample implementation could look like this:

```cs
public class PageLifetimeSupportingNavigationPage : NavigationPage
{
    public PageLifetimeSupportingNavigationPage(Page content)
        : base(content)
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        Pushed += (sender, e) => OpenPage(e.Page);

        Popped += (sender, e) => ClosePage(e.Page);

        PoppedToRoot += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var args = e as PoppedToRootEventArgs;
            if (args == null)
                return;

            foreach (var page in args.PoppedPages.Reverse())
                ClosePage(page);
        };
    }

    private static void OpenPage(Page page)
    {
        if (page is IPageLifetime navpage)
            navpage.OnOpening();
    }

    private static void ClosePage(Page page)
    {
        if (page is IPageLifetime navpage)
            navpage.OnClosed();

        page.BindingContext = null;
    }
}
```

Pages would implement the following interface:

```cs
public interface IPageLifetime
{
    void OnOpening();
    void OnClosed();
}
```

This interface could be implemented in a base class for all pages and then delegate it's calls to it's view model.

The navigation page and could be created like this:

```cs
var navigationPage = new PageLifetimeSupportingNavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

`MainPage` would be the root page to show.

Of course you could also just use `NavigationPage` in the first place and subscribe to it's events without inheriting from it.

Comment: If the goal is to cancel the navigation back, this doesn't work because the `Popped` event is fired after the navigation to the previous page is already done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be usefull, You need to hide the back button, and then replace with your own button:

```
public static UIViewController AddBackButton(this UIViewController controller, EventHandler ev){
    controller.NavigationItem.HidesBackButton = true;
    var btn = new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromFile("myIcon.png"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, ev);
    UIBarButtonItem[] items = new[] { btn };
    controller.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItems = items;
    return controller;
}

public static UIViewController DeleteBack(this UIViewController controller)
{
    controller.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItems = null;
    return controller;
}
```

Then call them into these methods:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    this.AddBackButton(DoSomething);
    UpdateFrames();
}

public override void ViewWillDisappear(Boolean animated)
{
    this.DeleteBackButton();
}

public void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    //Do a barrel roll
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way around is to use [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) Which allows you to implement nice popup. It uses another NavigationStack => Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack. So your page won't be wrap around the NavigationBar.

In your case I would simply

- Create a full page popup with opaque background
- Override ↩️ OnBackButtonPressed for Android on ⚠️ParentPage⚠️ with something like this:

  `protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
   {
       return Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack.Any();
    }`

Since the back-button affect the usual NavigationStack your parent would pop out whenever the user try to use it while your "popup is showing".

Now what? Xaml what ever you want to properly close your popup with all the check you want.

Problem solved for these targets

- [x] Android
- [x] iOS
- [-] Windows Phone (Obsolete. Use v1.1.0-pre5 if WP is needed)
- [x] UWP (Min Target: 10.0.16299)