# How to catch event with hardware back button on xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, keypress

I know the solution on Android

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
 {
        switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            // do something here 
            return true;
 }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); }
```

But i cant do it on the forms side. The focus is an Entry so the keyboard is visible and when i press hardware back button (keyboard disappear) i'd like to set my variable value.

**Edited:**

```
bool _tapped;

LwTeszt.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (LwTeszt.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    EntryTeszt.Focus();
                }

            };

            EntryTeszt.Unfocused += EntryTeszt_Unfocus;

        private void EntryTeszt_Unfocus(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            _tapped = true;
        }

        private void ViewCell_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (_tapped)
            {
                EntryTeszt.Unfocus();
                _tapped = false;
                return;
            }

            EntryTeszt.Focus();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have additional logic that you didn't post I think you might be overcomplicating things. I believe all you need to do is focus your entry on   `ViewCell_Tapped`

```
private void ViewCell_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EntryTeszt.Focus();
}
```

Forms will handle unfocusing your `Entry` for you when back is pressed and in that case you won't need the `LwTeszt.PropertyChanged`, `_tapped`, and the `EntryTeszt.Unfocused` parts.

Comment: I already tried. I need something fired only when backbutton pressed.

Comment: Why won't `Unfocused` work and what value are you trying to set?

Comment: Okay, here is my code,[I edited my question, check top] lets try.

Comment: And try with back button. _tapped will be true at the first time after button pressed (cuz EntryTeszt_Unfocus fired), so i need to tap 2 times after it. Its not good.

Comment: So from what I can make out from your code do you have a `ListView` with a custom viewcell that contains an `Entry` and you're trying to unfocus it when they click a different row?

Comment: No. I only have problems with the backbutton pressed! :D When keyboard is appear and press physical back button the keyboard disappear so EntryTeszt_Unfocus is working. This is fine. After it, tap an item in listview and nothing happens. You need to double tap it to display the keyboard again. This is the problem.

Comment: What's happening is after you hit back and click another cell `_tapped` is still true in `ViewCell_Tapped ` and you're calling `return` so it never reaches `EntryTeszt.Focus();` resulting in you having to tap it again which works because `_tapped` is now false.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Event you have to just override that and you can handle back button in Xamarin forms. Use below code for handling back button:

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        // your code
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
```

Also you can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657344/how-to-handle-cancel-back-navigation-in-xamarin-forms) for more information.

Comment: Its not good for me. When keyboard is appeared, this is not fired.