# Xamarin.forms android Prism handle hardware back button

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, prism, back-button

I am having issue while handling back button on android device. I want to handle navigation stack while user press hardware back button how I can achieve this?

Comment: What do you want specifically?

Comment: `protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed ();` is the event handler you are looking for. From the docs: Event that is raised when the hardware back button is pressed. This event is not raised on iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `OnBackButtonPressed()` function

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed (){
    //Handle your navigation here
}
```

Details from the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.onbackbuttonpressed?view=xamarin-forms)

**Note**: this will only work for Android, but that seems to be the only platform you are asking for. If you require a cross-platform solution, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657344/how-to-handle-cancel-back-navigation-in-xamarin-forms) question.

Comment: Thank you @Oscar Chambers does it possible to remove navigation stack while I am using prism so InavigationService will not accessible in code behind could you throw some light on it.

Comment: @JitendraJadav You shouldn't be navigating from the code behind , Prism is a framework for building loosely coupled, maintainable, and testable XAML applications in WPF, Windows 10 UWP, and Xamarin Forms.

Comment: @LeRoy right so OnBackButtonPressed it is only accessible in code behind while my navigation is on MVVM through how would I remove page or navigate through code behind that is my worry.

Comment: @JitendraJadav You ca only do it if you specify absolute URI - _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage");

Comment: @LeRoy thank you reply but still _navigationService.NavigateAsync will only accessible in ViewModel while OnBackButtonPressed will be in code behind so how I can access ViewModel? using Messanger but still this is every page I have to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know it's a good practice, but it worked to me.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    var vm = (SignInViewModel)BindingContext;

    vm.GoBackCommand.Execute();

    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

At ViewModel you can handle what you want to perform.