# `await DisplayAlert` not blocking code in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm relatively new to `async` and `await` so I currently have no idea where I've gone wrong or what to do but, my goal is to wait for the `DisplayAlert` dialog to close first (by pressing a button on it) before proceeding to execute next lines of code. I've tried both codes below and neither helped.

**Code Block A:** Shows the `DisplayAlert` but doesn't block the code from executing.

```
protected override async void OnDisappearing()
{
    if (!Global.EthernetWiring.IsFinished)
    {
        var operation = await DisplayAlert("Verify Action", "Are you sure you want to leave this page? Doing so will forfeit your exercise.", "Yes", "No");

        if (!operation)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    Global.EthernetWiring.IsT568A = true;
    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

**Code Block B:** Doesn't show the `DisplayAlert` and doesn't block the code from executing.

```
protected override async void OnDisappearing()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (!Global.EthernetWiring.IsFinished)
        {
            var operation = DisplayAlert("Verify Action", "Are you sure you want to leave this page? Doing so will forfeit your exercise.", "Yes", "No").Result;

            if (!operation)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        Global.EthernetWiring.IsT568A = true;
        base.OnDisappearing();
    });
}
```

PS: please don't ask about not using MVVM and other common practices. I have a short timeline and a rather huge scope for a project that i can't learn them all in time. Thanks.

Comment: What doy ou mean by "doesn't block the code from executing". Sure, async methods do not block, but the next line should be reached only after the user selected their choice.

Comment: From memory, once you are in `OnDisappearing`, it's too late to choose if you want to leave the page, it's already happening.

Comment: @KlausGütter that's how I understand it should work too. But for some reason, it doesn't hold from executing next lines of codes while the Alert is still open. for reference on `Code Block A`, see gif screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/OnG1ebo.gif

Comment: @DavidG apparently, its not just limited to `OnDisappearing` method. the same happens on other common user-defined methods.

Comment: @Nii According to your gif, you actually want to prevent navigation with back button until user click on Alert action, right? That is not possible in shared project, you need to do that separately for Android and iOS, like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657344/how-to-handle-cancel-back-navigation-in-xamarin-forms/46590851#46590851 It's not the problem with `await`, because when `OnDisappearing` is called the view of your page will already be gone. Furthermore, `OnDisappearing` is called when you switch to another app or lock the screen, so this will probably not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I also new to async and await but I think it should work if you delete `override` from the function.

If it doesn't work try this:

```
var operation = DisplayAlert("Verify Action", "Are you sure you want to leave this page? Doing so will forfeit your exercise.", "Yes", "No").GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

Comment: it blocks the UI Thread even with `async` modifier. When ran inside a `Task.Run(() => { ... });`, the dialog doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

> my goal is to wait for the DisplayAlert dialog to close first (by pressing a button on it) before proceeding to execute next lines of code.

You can try the following code.

```
 protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var Response = await DisplayAlert("Verify Action", "Are you sure you want to leave this page? Doing so will forfeit your exercise.", "Yes", "No");
       
        string Resuming = Response.ToString();
        if (Resuming=="false")
        {
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("this is test!!!!!!");
    }
```