# hide cancel and navitation in webview embbed B2C

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am doing an authentication in xamarin forms, using b2c, they asked me to embed the pop-up screen that triggers and in turn hide or eliminate both the cancel and the navigation bar, has someone done that part or otherwise modify it? (thanks in advance)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QnEb.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below references can be worked in your case:

**Hide Cancel button :**

***In custom policy*:**

Configure the `setting.showCancelButton` metadata item to `false` in the custom policy technical profile of the  sign in or sign up or page for it is requiredrequired.

*Example:*

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
  <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />

  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
    <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
    <Item Key=" setting.showCancelButton ">false</Item>
  </Metadata>
<InputClaims>….
….
</TechnicalProfile>
```

See self asserted technical profile [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/21068/azure-ad-b2c-why-continue-button-is-not-working-wh.html)  &  [Microsoft Q&A Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/21068/azure-ad-b2c-why-continue-button-is-not-working-wh.html)

***Through Xamarin Form:***

For Xamarin forms ,Use [Xamarin.Forms renderer to hide the "Cancel" button](https://gist.github.com/dkudelko/f256d10968c7c8b6a63447714d1d5b97) of a SearchBar on iOS using `Control.ShowsCancelButton = false`;

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    if (e.PropertyName == "Text")
    {   Control.ShowsCancelButton = false;}
}
```

**References:**

1. [Xamarin forms– iOS disable cancel button on SearchBar  (weblogs.us)](http://depblog.weblogs.us/2016/10/27/xamarin-forms-ios-disable-cancel-button-on-searchbar/)
2. [How to handle/cancel back navigation in Xamarin Forms-Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657344/how-to-handle-cancel-back-navigation-in-xamarin-forms)

---

**[Disable Navigation bar](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/513d4c35-b11d-448a-8d9e-f16ce8aad654/easy-way-to-hide-title-bar):**

If  you use webview in the NavigationPage or NavigationPage wrap the contentpage, Try  to add  `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` into your contentPage tags like following xaml, to disable navigation bar.

*Example:*

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"              
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"          
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FormsWebViewTest"              
                x:Class="FormsWebViewTest.MainPage"         
                 NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
                 ...........
                        .......//other part
</ContentPage>
```

Or
[SetHasNavigationBar](https://dotnetco.de/hide-status-bar-in-xamarin-forms-for-ios-and-android/) to false on your navigation page (in content page constructor).

ex:

```
public MyPage()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
}
```