# How to handle backbutton on .Net Maui?

Tags: maui

I need to handle the back button action in .Net Maui.

I'm not talking about the device backbutton. But the navigation page back button :

[image]

I tried this code but it works only on the device back button and not navigation page back button.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{        
    // Do something here 
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

How can I handle that?

Comment: Do you want to intercept it and prevent the user from navigating back if a certain condition isn't met or do you simply want to trigger some action whenever the user navigates back?

Comment: I'm in the first case @ewerspej : intercept it and prevent the user from navigating back if a certain condition isn't met

Comment: You should add that to the question, then. I don't know if this is possible in MAUI or how much effort it would take, but I know that this wasn't directly possible in Xamarin.Forms without custom renderers (see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657344/how-to-handle-cancel-back-navigation-in-xamarin-forms#46590851)). Have you tried what @rentoulis proposed?

Answer (score 3):

I think that this will help: "Back button appearance and behavior can be redefined by setting the BackButtonBehavior attached property to a BackButtonBehavior object", according to [MAUI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-6.0#back-button-behavior).

Using "Command" property you can define the actions to executed when back-button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Shell Navigation back button by using the back button behavior.

- Command, of type ICommand, which is executed when the back button is
  pressed.
- CommandParameter, of type object, which is the parameter that's
  passed to the Command.

Here is the information about [Back button behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-6.0#back-button-behavior).

Answer (score 2):

**Use the below code to handle the back button in MAUI app
and the same code will work for WebView as well.**

```cs
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if (WebView.CanGoBack)
        {
            WebView.GoBack();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            return false;
        }
    }
```